# how a string return from ajax can be used to populate html table using php mysql, jquery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I want to populate html table with the data returned from ajax. How will i do that. Below is the string which returned from ajax :

﻿﻿1-1.00-2013-2014,2-2.00-2013-2014,3-3.00-2013-2014,4-4.00-2013-2014,6-5.00-2013-2014,8-6.00-2013-2014,10-7.00-2013-2014,12-8.00-2013-2014,16-9.00-2013-2014,20-10.00-2013-2014,24-11.00-2013-2014,30-12.00-2013-2014,36-13.00-2013-2014,48-14.00-2013-2014,60-15.00-2013-2014,61-16.00-2013-2014,

---

What comes in my mind is to split the whole string like this :

```
var dataarr = data.split(',');
```

after spliting this, split again which will convert into three separate arrays

```
var dataarr = data.split('-');
```

and then using a loop populates html table. But don't know how to do accomplish in php. I have searched the net. I don't want to use "json" instead try to achieve using "mysqli" Please guide me?

Comment: I don't understand the question. After you got the response from the Ajax call, you  only can handle it with Javascript. PHP is only processed at a full page reload.

Comment: yeah the string which you have seen is the data which was return from ajax.   i want to populate html table with this data using data.split(). But I dont have any idea how to do it

Comment: **1st :** Provide us an example of the final html table filled with your data. **2nd :** If you start by using Ajax, you will need JavaScript to alter the table to fill it with the value you take back from your php script, but using php after Ajax is not possible since you need to do asynchronous changes on your view.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `.split()` in conjunction with `.map()` to achieve this:

```js
$(function() {

  $('#create').change(function() {
    createTable($(this).val(), $('#tblBdy'))
  });

  function createTable(data, tbl) {
    var bdy = $.map(data.split(','), function(tr, i) {
      return $('<tr></tr>').html(
        $.map(tr.split('-'), function(td, i) {
          return $('<td></td>').html(td);
        })
      );
    });
    tbl.html(bdy);
  }

  $('#tblBdy').on('click', 'tr', function() {
    var tableData2 = $(this).closest("tr").children("td").map(function() {
      return $(this).text();
    });
    $('#bx1txt').val($.trim(tableData2[0]));
    $('#bx2txt').val($.trim(tableData2[1]));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="create">
  <option value="">Select one</option>
  <option value="6-5.00-2013-2014,8-6.00-2013-2014,10-7.00-2013-2014,12-8.00-2013-2014,16-9.00-2013-2014,20-10.00-2013-2014,24-11.00-2013-2014,30-12.00-2013-2014,36-13.00-2013-2014,48-14.00-2013-2014,60-15.00-2013-2014,61-16.00-2013-2014">first group</option>
  <option value="1-1.00-2013-2014,2-2.00-2013-2014,3-3.00-2013-2014,4-4.00-2013-2014,6-5.00-2013-2014,8-6.00-2013-2014,10-7.00-2013-2014,12-8.00-2013-2014,16-9.00-2013-2014,20-10.00-2013-2014,24-11.00-2013-2014,30-12.00-2013-2014,36-13.00-2013-2014,48-14.00-2013-2014,60-15.00-2013-2014,61-16.00-2013-2014">second group</option>
  <option value="3-3.00-2013-2014,4-4.00-2013-2014,6-5.00-2013-2014,8-6.00-2013-2014,10-7.00-2013-2014,12-8.00-2013-2014,16-9.00-2013-2014,20-10.00-2013-2014,24-11.00-2013-2014">third group</option>
  <input type="text" id="bx1txt" value="" />
  <input type="text" id="bx2txt" value="" />
</select>
<br>
<br>
<table border="1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Quantity</th>
      <th>Price</th>
      <th>Start</th>
      <th>End</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="tblBdy"></tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks a million for providing me the code. everthing works perfectly except one small thing - whenever i select another value from the dropdown the table doesnot show the change value. Change value is shown only when I refreshes the page and select a value from the dropdown. How to accomplish this - ie. change of table content when the user selects another value in the drop down. Please guide.

Comment: @Suneet If I understand you correctly, the edit above should resolve this for you

Comment: Thanks  for repying. I have already checked this using javascript console. Everytime i select a value from dropdown a new string appears. But this doesnot change the content of the table. it changes only when i refreshes the page and selecting again value from dropdown

Comment: One more query, => after the table is populated, if we want to show clicked column data of the table in a textbox how we can accomplish this ?? Pls help. I am using this jquery but this is not working as shown below :                                  $('table#insallrates tbody tr').click(function() { var tableData2 = $(this) .closest("tr").children("td").map(function() { 
 return $(this).text();
}).get();
        $('#bx1txt').val($.trim(tableData2[0]));
$('#bx2txt').val($.trim(tableData2[1]));  });      Please help

Comment: @Suneet Updated, the issue is that the way you were trying only works if the elements exist on the page when the page loads, if the elements are generated dynamically, like you're doing, you have to use `.on()` to bind to an element that does exist on page load and have it listen for clicks on the dynamically added elements like `$('#tblBdy').on('click', 'tr', function () { //code goes here..... });` this is called "Event Delegation" see https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/ for a better understanding

Comment: It's no different than the working example shown here but sure http://jsfiddle.net/DelightedDoD/bLpyhfwf/    : )

Comment: Thanks for the example. May i know what all .js you have inculded in the code? is it " jquery-2.1.3.js" or some more. Pls reply

Comment: NP, just jquery, if there were any other external libraries being used in the fiddle, it would show the number of linked files in the area indicated in this screenshot:  http://prntscr.com/6x9hcl

Comment: I asked because when I put all the code at one place and try to run it, it does show the drop down with text boxes along with the heading of the table but it is not running

Comment: @Suneet more than likely, you have place the javascript in such a way that it is called before the page fully loads.  So the bind is attempted before the button actually exists on the page, ty putting all of the js in a on ready function like `$(function() { // all the code goes here... });` This will make sure the code is not run until the page has fully load. SO and jsFiddle both wrap your code in  this function (or one like it) automatically. I have updated the above to include this explicitly

Comment: I have placed the code somewhat like this as shown below :  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <script src=" http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.js"></script>
  <script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
   
    $('#create').change(function() {
      createTable($(this).val(), $('#tblBdy'))
    });                                                                                       Is this ok ?

Comment: @Suneet is your file viewable online or can you put the whole page in a jsfiddle?

Comment: @Suneet You're missing  `);` at the end of your dom ready function, see http://jsfiddle.net/DelightedDoD/yeqr6tud/2/

Comment: Yeah! I found it and sorry for that. and Thank you very much for the code.

Comment: You're quite welcome, dont forget to mark your question as answered : )